# Jquery show info in popup after jquery post method if link is yet hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made popup with actor info if user hover on link whith actor name. But if user hovering links very fast its often can be 2 popup in same time. Is it possible to check if link is yet hovered so popup will show certain info on certain link?
Here is my code

```
    $('.persons a').mouseenter(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var elem = $(this);

    $('#person_info').remove();

    $.post(
        '/site/get_person_info',
        'url=' + url,
        function(data) {
            if (data != 'error') {

                function show_creator_info(url) {
                    if ($('.persons a:hover').length != 0) {
                        $(elem).append(data);
                    }
                }
                show_creator_info(url);
            }
        }
    );

    $('.persons a').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#person_info').remove();
    });

});
```

and here is a demo [enter link description here](https://hdlava.me/films/smertelnaya-igra-2.html)
div "В ролях"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable called `loading` to know if you're fetching data or not and do not request again if loading is true.

```
var loading = false;

$('.persons a').mouseenter(function(){
    if (loading) return;

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var elem = $(this);    
    $('#person_info').remove();
    loading = true;
    $.post(
        '/site/get_person_info',
        'url=' + url,
        function(data) {
            if (data != 'error') {
                function show_creator_info(url) {
                    if ($('.persons a:hover').length != 0) {
                        $(elem).append(data);
                    }
                }
                show_creator_info(url);
            }
            loading = false;
        }
    );

    $('.persons a').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#person_info').remove();
    });    
});
```